# excel make a dependent list in two directions?

Tags: excel, validation

I have two dependent lists, in two-column A and B, and by using "data validation" if I choose a value in A it will generate a list in column B, the question is:
if A is empty how to show a list in B which contains all possibilities, and how to make A depend on B knowing that B is dependent on A.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: So the two dropdowns are already working so that dropdown A makes dropdown B pick one list or the other. Now you want dropdown B to pick all the possible entries if dropdown A is empty. Why not create a third list with all possibilities that is selected when A is empty?

Comment: thank you, I did it like you mentioned using an if statement and a lookup function so it's work, still have a question, if I pick from B, can it be generated in A ?? all inside the "data validation".

Comment: Smells like a job for a macro. Use a [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (on column G for example) to have All values Fruits & vegetables then create a named range "All" then within the validation done under "B" column write this

=IF($A2="",All,INDIRECT($A2))